# Unable to start Docker on Oracle Linux

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I followed so many link, but did not get any working solution.

```
docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
```

When I do

```
systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
```

When I execute

```
systemctl enable docker.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: vagrant
Password:
```

I get above error. I am using Oracle Linux

```
uname -a
Linux 10-10-150-104 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Aug 2 06:49:08 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: restart the docker service and check the logs of `journalctl -u docker.service`, u may find some clue.

Comment: also check [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configure-docker-to-start-on-boot)

Comment: When it says, `Authenticating as: vagrant`, are you entering the password as well?
Usually the password for vagrant box is just `vagrant`. From the above, it's not clear if you are entering the password or not. Did you try your command with `sudo`? Take a look at this - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1214 and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1214#issuecomment-141397939